# Moment not correctly parsing time in milliseconds

Tags: datetime, time, momentjs, unix-timestamp

I have the following code:

```
job_created_at_timestamp = moment(job_created_at_timestamp_milliseconds).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:MM:SS A');
```

Where `job_created_at_timestamp_milliseconds` is a timestamp in milliseconds, for example: 1463422849081.

Moment is not correctly converting these timestamps, for example 1463422849081 is converted to 2016-05-16 02:05:08 PM, when it should be 2016-05-16 02:20:49 PM.

I also tried to 'reconvert' the timestamp into a unix time:

```
moment.unix(job_created_at_timestamp_milliseconds).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:MM:SS A');
```

but that timestamp is less correct.

I verified that the milliseconds are correct using [this website](http://currentmillis.com/). Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp format was wrong:

```
moment(job_created_at_timestamp_milliseconds).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss A');
```